# Get full value of a wrapped text cell in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell A1. When I click on it, the "wrap text" icon is activated and the value appears like this:

1 parent
1 child

In vba, when I try to get the value of the cell like this:

```
Dim value As String
value=Cells(1,1).Value
```

I only get "1 parent", how can I get the full value of the cell?

Comment: Are you sure about this? That is **not** the behavior that I observe if I test it: http://i.imgur.com/FYx0d79.png

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? I'm using 2003 and I don't have this issue at all.

Comment: `Debug.Print Len(value)` gives you what?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The split function will split text strings based on any number of characters. In this case, we are splitting by Chr(10) which is the line break character. Essentially you split the text into parts, and the split occurs at any line break, and then you put them back together in a string variable called "value". Now "value" can be used in any place you would like the full string.

```
Dim value as string
Dim x as Variant
Dim i as integer

x = split(Cells(1,1),Chr(10))
for i = 0 to ubound(x)
   value = value & x(i)
Next i
```

Comment: So... how does this answer the question? I'm not saying it _doesn't_ but a little explanation would go a long way to improving the answer.

Comment: Apologies, many folks don't care for an explanation, just want a solution to their problem. Edited to include an explanation of how this works.

Comment: Better, but the OP supposedly isn't even getting the Line Break character in their return value of `Cells(1,1).Value`, which you've used here within the `Split()` function (`.Value` is the default property of `Cells`). Hence all the comments on the question stating that the problem is proving difficult to reproduce.

Comment: I'm just offering up how I would approach this problem. If my solution doesn't work for the OP, they can comment with what doesn't work and I will attempt to correct my answer to suit their needs. When I posted my answer I had not seen any of the comments.